# ODE and domains of existence and uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the one parameter family of integral curves and state the domains of deﬁnition , existence  and uniqueness ( validity ) of the solution. Use the existence and uniqueness theorem to substantiate your answer. Note your solution should be an explicit function of the stated variable.

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\sin(t)}y ,\quad y=y(t)$$

For the family of curves I got $$y=(-0.5\cos(t)+C)^{0.5}$$

but I need help with the domains